# Remove words inside the brackets

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm quite a newbie with javascript so I was wondering how do you remove the words inside the brackets & remove brackets? also I want to remove the words before the colon and then replace the brackets with a comma except for the last word. So for example if the string contains:

```
language:chinese (29)parody:hyouka (73)character:fuyumi irisu (12)houtarou oreki (12)group:shuudan bouryoku (41)artist:murasaki syu (49)misc:schoolgirl (11)nakadashi (11)acting like a pet (6)
```

then the output would become

```
chinese,hyouka,fuyumi irisu,houtarou oreki,shuudan bouryoku,murasaki syu,schoolgirl,nakadashi,acting like a pet
```

How can I do this with javascript? This is the code and it's not working

```
var str = "language:chinese (29)parody:hyouka (73)character:fuyumi irisu (12)houtarou oreki (12)group:shuudan bouryoku (41)artist:murasaki syu (49)misc:schoolgirl (11)nakadashi (11)acting like a pet (6)";

var tags = str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, ','));
final = tags.replace(/.*(?=:)/i, "");
alert(final);
```

Comment: i added my code but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [^)]+ to indicate that here is no closing  bracket after opening:

```
var str = "language:chinese (29)parody:hyouka (73)character:fuyumi irisu (12)houtarou oreki (12)group:shuudan bouryoku (41)artist:murasaki syu (49)misc:schoolgirl (11)nakadashi (11)acting like a pet (6)";  

var tags = str.replace(/\s?\([^\)]+\)/g, ',')
              .replace(/[^:]+:([^,]+),/g,'$1,')
              .replace(/,$/,'');
alert(tags);​
```

even simple:

```
var tags = str.replace(/([^:]+:)?([^(]+)\s\([^\)]+\)/g,'$2,')
              .replace(/,$/,'');
```

Comment: I noticed your code removes the word after the colon. I actually wanted to remove the words before the colon

Comment: is there a way to remove the last comma at the end?